# Changing a value of a cell based on another cell

Tags: excel, vba

What I want to do is if column O contains "weekend" then change the value of column M cells to "3".

```
Sub weekly_weekend()
  lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  For x = 2 To lastrow
   If InStr(1, Sheet1.Range("O" & x).Value, UCase("weekend"), 1) > 0 Then 
     Sheet1.Range("M" & x).Value = "3"
  Next x

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So what's not working? Is there an error? If so, what error and on what line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you're getting the last row of the `column A`, and this will prevent the `For` to be executed. To fix your code, you can proceed in multiple ways.

#### Using Range

- One is to use the `Range` property, so you can explicitly write your column name, like this:

  ```
  Sub weekly_weekend()
      lastrow = Sheet1.Range("O" & Sheet1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      For x = 2 To lastrow
          If InStr(1, Sheet1.Range("O" & x).Value, UCase("weekend"), 1) > 0 Then Sheet1.Range("M" & x).Value = "3"
      Next x

      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End Sub
  ```

#### Picking up the right column

- Or you can simply pick the right number of the column you want (in this case `column O` is `15`), like this:

  ```
  Sub weekly_weekend()
      lastrow = Sheet1.Cells(Sheet1.Rows.Count, 15).End(xlUp).Row
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      For x = 2 To lastrow
          If InStr(1, Sheet1.Range("O" & x).Value, UCase("weekend"), 1) > 0 Then Sheet1.Range("M" & x).Value = "3"
      Next x

      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  End Sub
  ```

> **Note**: Please note that if you **add** or **remove** columns, with the second method you'll need to remember to change the column index in your code accordingly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The only thing wrong with the line I see is a missing but definitely only optional `Sheet` qualifier before the `Rows.Count`. Can you elaborate?